# Store the data on a timeseries database

Tags: javascript, python, database, api, time-series

I have been using an API to fetch some timeseries data and using Grafana to visualise that data. But lately I had a few issues that I had to solve and for that I need to go back in time and for some reason if the API I'm using has some server errors or anything then basically I can't do my work. So, I was wondering if someone could help me guide as to how can I set up a continuous data flow pipeline where the data is fetched automatically from the API and is stored in a timeseries DB can be InfluxDB or TimescaleDB. And then the idea is to use that database to visualize the data instead of using API. Another reason for this is that API always has restrictions in terms of how many datapoints can be retrieved at a time and this limits my visualization or have to create multiple queries which is to be honest pain in the ****.

Any and all the help is highly appreciated as I'm really new into this kind of work and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can consider to use Python to run the api every x interval and write to the database ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try following steps:

1. Set up an [InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/install/) instance
2. Collect data through HTTP API and store it in InfluxDB via [Telegraf's HTTP Plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http): here you need to configure two settings: [[inputs.http]] and [[outputs.influxdb]]
3. Set up the [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/getting-started/get-started-grafana-influxdb/) which talks to InfluxDB

[Here](https://medium.com/@itsHabib/send-metrics-to-influxdb-with-telegrafs-http-plugin-fe90ea3ddf46) is a working sample you could learn from.